# How i can optimize this query?

Tags: mysql

I know that IN, NOT IN in a mysql query (that is deprecated) is not performance wise, but this is what i need to achieve. There is any other way to achieve the same result in a better way? Loc_table is a list of users with id and name, table 1 and 2 are two different task tables where i register among other things if the user finnished the tasks of that specific table (boolean yes no). The query below work ok but is slow. Any help will be appreciated.

```
loc = mysql_query("SELECT loc_id, name,
    CASE
    WHEN loc_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM table 1 WHERE done = 0 GROUP BY loc_id) THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END AS active_in_1,
    CASE
    WHEN loc_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM table2 WHERE done = 0 GROUP BY loc_id) THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END AS active_in_2
    FROM loc_table L LEFT JOIN table_2 C ON C.loc_id = L.loc_id LEFT JOIN table_1 A ON A.loc_id = L.loc_id
    WHERE C.done = 0 OR A.done = 0 GROUP BY loc_id ORDER BY name") or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use subselect in you query

```
SELECT loc_id, name,
    CASE
    WHEN A.loc_id is null THEN 0 ELSE 1
    END AS active_in_1,
    CASE
    WHEN c.loc_id is null THEN 0 ELSE 1
    END AS active_in_1        FROM loc_table L LEFT JOIN table_2 C ON C.loc_id = L.loc_id LEFT JOIN table_1 A ON A.loc_id = L.loc_id
    WHERE C.done = 0 OR A.done = 0
```

Where is group functions for

```
 GROUP BY loc_id ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Hello rpc! thanks, i made a mistake in my question, im updating it, because the id column have a diff name in the tasks tables, running the query give me other results

Answer (score 0):

Well writing another query i found the solution by chance, it reduce the execution time from 4 sec to 40 ms

```
select L.loc_id ,L.name,
CASE
WHEN (SELECT count(*) from table_1 where user_id = L.loc_id and done = 0) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0
END as active_in_1,
CASE
WHEN (SELECT count(*) from table_2 where user_id = L.loc_id and done = 0) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0
END as active_in_2
FROM loc_table L group by loc_id
HAVING active_in_1 != 0 OR active_in_2 != 0
ORDER BY name;
```